# php functions and mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
select1($conn); 
function select2 ($conn,$id ,$name)
{   
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT def FROM define WHERE wordkey = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $id);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->bind_result($def);
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo "here"; // for testing
        $wordArray += $def; 
        //I will make a call to the js function here sending id, name and wordArray
    }  
    //$stmt->close();
}

function select1 ($conn){
    $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT id , name FROM words");
    $stmt2->execute(); 
    $stmt2->bind_result($id, $name);
    while($stmt2->fetch()) {
        select2 ($conn,$id ,$name);
    }
}
?>
```

I want to ask question I have words table and def table. in def table i have multiple definitions for the same words.id. Is it possible to select them in one query statement ?

words table have

```
id , name
```

def table have

```
id, wordkey , definition
```

I want to retrieve name and for each name select all its definitions so that I will then call a javascript function (id, name, defArray) to display each name with the array of its definitions. I thought of doing it through 2 select statement, but the problem is the select2 function is not working. Please Help!

Comment: You can not call javascript function from your php code. it is not possible

Comment: YES, look up the JOIN syntax in the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) or find a tutorial

Comment: that is not the problem. I have not add that part though in select2 function and it is still not working

Comment: I dont see any javascript in this code, so WHY have you tagged it with javascript

Comment: @RiggsFolly join will not work for me as it will not help me in calling another function

Comment: You dont need another function. you can get all the results from a single query using a JOIN

Comment: but then I will result set for example name1|def1, name1|def2, name1|def3 that will help me as I want to send to the javascript function name1 and array of defs for name1 and so on

Comment: Actually either you have described your tables incorrectly or the Query in the `select2` function is incorrect

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: And you are not doing anything with the data you generate in `select2` the data you try and create in that function will not be visible anywhere else in your code as it is only visible in the local scope of the `select2` function

Comment: 1. why isn't `$stmt->bind_param()` there. 2. would it work with $id directly in the query string. $id is passed by reference so it may face a strange behavior.

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you so much!